# Adding password protection with openpyxl in Django project

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I tried to add password protection the excel file as shown below, but the protection is not happening, any body can tell us what is wrong here.

```
def export_member_to_xlsx(request):
    user_queryset = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False)

    response = HttpResponse(
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    )
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={date}-members.xlsx'.format(
        date=datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    )
    workbook = Workbook()
    worksheet = workbook.active
    worksheet.title = 'Members'
    worksheet.protection = WorkbookProtection(workbookPassword='password', lockStructure=True)
    columns = [
        'User',
        'Email',
        'First Name',
        'Last Name',
        'Member Since',
        'Subscription Expiry',
    ]
    row_num = 1
    for col_num, column_title in enumerate(columns, 1):
        cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
        cell.value = column_title
    for member in user_queryset:
        row_num += 1
        row = [
            member.username,
            member.email,
            member.first_name,
            member.last_name,
            member.date_joined,
            member.subscriptions.current_period_end,
        ]
        for col_num, cell_value in enumerate(row, 1):
            cell = worksheet.cell(row=row_num, column=col_num)
            cell.value = cell_value
    workbook.save(response)
    return response
```

I tried the same protection code before workbook.save, but still it doesn't work